# How to extract details from report having date in yyyy-mm-dd format in a row untill next yyyy-mm-dd entry founds in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have one report(report.log) which has entries like this

```
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-18
---------------------------------------------------

details1   
details2    
....   
....

Following are access details for date: 2015-02-19
----------------------------------------------------

line1                                                                        
line2   
....  
....

Following are access details for date: 2015-02-20
-------------------------------------------------------

line1                                                                        
line2   
....  
....
```

I want to write a script which will ask for inputting single date in yyyy-mm-dd format(output of this should be Following are access details for date : yyyy-mm-dd up to and excluding new entry line of "following are access details for date")or range like from 2014-02-09 to 2014-02-20(output of this should be Following are access details for date : 2014-02-09 up to and including second date in range 2014-02-20), that means outputting all entries starting from first date to last date in date range.

Please also note new lines after and before Following are ... line in report

Comment: can any of the `details1, ...` lines also contain a date like `2015-02-19`? Also, you tag is `shell` is this for **bourne** shell `sh` or Bash, or zsh? Would a Bash solution work?

Comment: details1,2 or line1,2 or .... would not contain date like 2015-02-19 and it is for bourne shell bash, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example making use of `d1=$(date -d "somedate" +%s)` to convert to seconds to epoch. Then for then next day `d2=$((d1 + 86400))`. That allows you to find the line in the file containing the first date and read all lines until the second day is found. Let me know if you have any questions:

```
#!/bin/sh

dt1=$(date -d "$1" +%s)   # date provided by input
dt1f=$(date -d @$dt1 +%F) # date1 formatted in YYYY-MM-DD
dt2=$((dt1 + 86400))      # add one day to it
dt2f=$(date -d @$dt2 +%F) # date2 formatted in YYYY-MM-DD

ifn=${2:-loghdg.txt}      # input file

# printf "\nDate Range: %s - %s\n\n" "$(date -d @$dt1 +%F)" "$(date -d @$dt2 +%F)"
printf "\nDate Range: %s - %s\n\n" "$dt1f" "$dt2f"

# read each line in file
while read -r line; do

    arr=( $line )                   # read line into array
    for i in ${arr[@]}; do          # for each word in line
        [ $i == $dt1f ] && found=1  # if date1 found, print lines
        [ $i == $dt2f ] && found=0  # if date2 found, stop printing
    done

    [ "$found" == "1" ] && printf " %s\n" "$line"

done <"$ifn"
```

**input file**

```
$ cat loghdg.txt
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-18
details1
details2
....
....
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-19
line1
line2
....
....
Following are access details for date: 2015-02-20
line1
line2
....
....
```

**output/use**

```
$ sh date-day-diff.sh 2015-02-18

Date Range: 2015-02-18 - 2015-02-19

 Following are access details for date: 2015-02-18
 details1
 details2
 ....
 ....
```

A modification to accept both a `start` and `end` date is fairly simple.

**Modified to accept start + end date**

```
dt1=$(date -d "$1" +%s)   # start date provided by input
dt1f=$(date -d @$dt1 +%F) # date1 formatted in YYYY-MM-DD
dt2=$(date -d "$2" +%s)   # end date provided by input
dt2f=$(date -d @$dt2 +%F) # date2 formatted in YYYY-MM-DD

ifn=${3:-loghdg.txt}      # input file
```

**new output**

```
$ sh date-day-diff.sh 2015-02-18 2015-02-20

Date Range: 2015-02-18 - 2015-02-20

 Following are access details for date: 2015-02-18
 details1
 details2
 ....
 ....
 Following are access details for date: 2015-02-19
 line1
 line2
 ....
 ....
```

Comment: Hi, I need to take two date entries as input arguments, in your solution it is working for that provided date only, and though it shows Date Range: 2015-02-18 - 2015-02-19 in output, data of only 2015-02-18 is fetching this.
I think this works perfectly when we need data of only one date. Could you also suggest code for output when we provide two distinct dates as argument and it fetches data for that range(including both dates). Many thanks

Comment: Sure, to accept an end date, you will need to give the script 3 arguments. (e.g. `script.sh date1 date2 filename`) To do this, simply change `dt2=$((dt1 + 86400))` to `dt2=$(date -d "$2" +%s)`, then change the argument for the input filename `ifn=${3:-loghdg.txt}`

Comment: @david-c-rankin, Yes I think it should work for date issue, but I'm not getting output after modifications for input file like this, inputreport="$3" # input file echo "Usage: ./script.sh <date1 in yyyy-mm-dd format> <date2 in yyyy-mm-dd format> <name of the report>" echo "Example ./script.sh 2014-02-16 2014-02-20 report.log" echo "Also, if you want report for single date, please input same date in first and second argument". Will this logic work here from for loop, [ $i == $dt1f ] && found=1 [ $i == $dt2f ] && found=0 done [ "$found" == "1" ] && printf " %s\n" "$line" done <"$inputreport"

Comment: Putting the same date in twice wont work for a single day with the existing code. You need to put in the next day for the second argument. For a single day use: e.g. `2014-02-16 2014-02-17`. Otherwise, you simply need to add logic that tests if the dates are equal and then increments day2 by 1 day. (e.g.  `[ $dt1 -eq $dt2] && dt2=$( date -d "$(date -d @$dt1) + 1 day" +%s)` )

Comment: Get rid of the `:-loghdg.txt` from `ifn=${3:-loghdg.txt}`, that is just the default file I stored your test data in on my computer.  (short for **log heading.txt**) The `done <"$ifn"` is how you get the data from the file into the `while` loop. It could just be `<"$3"`. (**redirection from file**) To have it work the way you want, just add an `if [ $1 == $2 ]; then dt2=$( date -d "$(date -d @$dt1) + 1 day" +%s); else dt2=$(date -d "$2" +%s); fi` before setting the `dt1f` and `dt2f` variables.